# Getting error : CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bundle, dagger-hilt

Hey I am trying to get a bundle with hilt but I get this error.

my gradle

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2'
```

I saw that the solution was to add these libraries but it didn't work for me

I want to open a screen with BizBundle but I get an error

full error is:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.smartlife.ninovas, PID: 8861
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartlife.ninovas/com.thingclips.smart.scene.construct.detail.SceneDetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3431)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:91)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:90)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:116)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
at com.thingclips.smart.scene.construct.detail.SceneDetailViewModelFactoryKt.createViewModel(SceneDetailViewModelFactory.kt:14)
at com.thingclips.smart.scene.construct.detail.SceneDetailActivity.onCreate(SceneDetailActivity.kt:184)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8023)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8007)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3404)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

and this is the line:

```
    IThingSceneBusinessService iThingSceneBusinessService = MicroContext.findServiceByInterface(IThingSceneBusinessService.class.getName());
```

if(null != iThingSceneBusinessService && HomeModel.getHomeID() != 0) {
iThingSceneBusinessService.addSceneBean(MainPage.this, HomeModel.getHomeID(), 1234);
}

Comment: You should add more info on the error you are getting.

Comment: i did this too :)

Answer (score 0):

*I hope, this suggestion worked your side\n*
*Step 1: Build.Gradle(modual_app)*
*dependency side:- *

```
//hilt
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

//lifecycle
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"
```

*plugin side:- *

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
```

*Step 2: Build.gradle(project_name)*
*plugin side:- *

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "2.44" apply false
```

*Step 3: * *Sync Now*
*Step 4: * * clicked file -> setting -> search "Gradle" -> check JDK -> change jdk11 *
*Step 5: invalid cache and restart*

Comment: They are already in my gralde so its didnt work :/

Comment: update your gradle version. go to the "Gradle-wrapper-properties" - distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

Comment: i did too but now i cant start the app getting A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
error

Comment: Please copy file code and and create new app and add package name and paste your all file then open your new project. then again cant work after that all file upload on git-hub and provide your git-hub link on my what's app number "+918999539845"